Access files in Databricks Workspace in runtime version > 11.3 with python
I have a question about if it is possible to access (read and write) files in common Workspace in Databricks with python? I know that according to docs "In Databricks Runtime 11.3 LTS and above, you can directly manipulate workspace files in Databricks."
I am using runtime 14.3 at the moment, but nothing like described in the documentation works for me when I try to read/write files in the common Workspace. My goal is to generate the file in the notebook in specific folder in common Workspace (not in my personal Workspace), and save it in the same folder.
I know that it's possible to access small Catalog tables without spark, using module "deltalake" for example, and path which is modification of the path provides by Catalog (like in Catalog>Table Details, there is Storage Location like s3://xxx-dev/yyy/ccc/zzzzz/tables/6abs-def654-ger654, and I can use it for table access, instead of what is provided when I click on "Copy full table name to clipboard" link near Table name in Catalog). So there might be a similar path (to s3 or other place), but for notebooks.
Any suggestions?

You question is very generic.
To read:
# Read a file from the workspace
with open("/dbfs/workspace/<folder>/<file>.txt", "r") as file:
    content = file.read()
    print(content)

To write:
# Write a file to the workspace
with open("/dbfs/workspace/<folder>/<file>.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write("This is a test file.")

Sometime I use dbutils API, here is some examples:
# Write a file to the workspace
dbutils.fs.put("workspace:/shared_folder/example.txt", "This is a test file.")

# Read the file
content = dbutils.fs.head("workspace:/shared_folder/example.txt")
print(content)

Lets me know if above is not working, I will help more.
Cheers
